# WhatsApp native app on Ubuntu

Tags: whatsapp

Is there any way we can run WhatsApp natively on Ubuntu 20.04 lts desktop and "not the web-client".

Answer (score 1):

At this time, November 2020, there is no official WhatsApp client you could install on a Linux distribution, however, you can install an unofficial WhatsApp client **at your own risk**.

Here are some of the unofficial WhatsApp clients available on snap store:

- https://snapcraft.io/walc
- https://snapcraft.io/whatsdesk
- https://snapcraft.io/whatsapp-for-linux

Comment: I'd really think 10 times before using a 3rd party app for my messaging applications, as they may or may not have the time, skill set and continuous attention to vulnerabilities so as to provide a sufficiently secure application, and then also because there can only be certain amounts of  accountability in that scenario, compared to a large company official core application. Some would argue otherwise, of course.

Comment: @matanster To be honest, I actually think 10 times before using anything outside official repositories, that's why I said "you can install an unofficial WhatsApp client **at your own risk**".
My country has blocked most of the messengers and WhatsApp is the best thing we have so I use it quite often and it bothers me that I have to open it up in the browser every time but still, I never used any 3rd party app for it.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu gets its software from people like you: Volunteer packagers and contributors. This is an important way for community members to contribute to Ubuntu.

- If you want to help package software into .debs for the next release of Ubuntu, start at http://mentors.debian.net. Most deb packages come from Debian.
- If you want to help package Snaps, start at http://snapcraft.io

There are few contributors working on "drive-by" packaging requests. If you truly care about getting your software into Ubuntu, you must do a bit of the work yourself.